# Application notified when an EventKit event fires

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, eventkit

Is it possible for my app to be notified when an event from a given calendar fires? I tried looking in EventKit for some delegate property, to no avail.

I want my app to run a certain code when a given event fires up.

Answer (score 1):

Register your application in notification center, and create local notification instance , in the property fire date of local notification instance just give your event end time(alarms if you specified for events in the event store).Automatically user will be notified even if your app is not running. Hope this help you